# Calculating a sum of function values

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula

I have 10 cells, `A1:A10`. Each contains a number. I'd like to calculate the following sum, where p<sub>i</sub> is cell's number:

[image]

**How do I do this without making additional/temporal cells?**

In other words, how to convert the sum depicted above into a `sum` function from Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10)/(5+ROW(1:10)))
```

[image]

Comment: Was looking at `SUMPRODUCT` but could not wrap my had around it. Thank you so much!